# JPA self-reference OneToMany mapping with extra fields

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I have a `Phone` and a `Phone4Phone_Map` tables, the second table set up rules so when a phone is broken it can be changed for another similar phone.

```
Phone:
------
idPhone INT(11) PK
name VARCHAR()
model VARCHAR()
price LONG

Phone4Phone_Map:
----------------
idPhone_in INT(11) PK
idPhone_out INT(11) PK
valid_since TIMESTAMP
reason VARCHAR()
```

I'm having a hard time to understand how to do the mappings. I was wondering if a `@OneToMany` self-reference on `Phone` would just do fine, but I don't know how to include the extra fields from `Phone4Phone_Map` (`valid_since` and `reason`), this is me thinking of not mapping the second table which I don't know if it's even possible.

Comment: As you see, a self-referenced `@OneToMany` won't work because one single telephone can have many substitutes/be a substitute for many. If you delete the additional fields, you might do with a `@ManyToMany`; otherwise you need the second entity.

Comment: You would need a @OneToMany to the Phone4Phone_Map. As you can see there might be requirement that one phone can be replaced with many phones, say for example that iPhone5 can be replaced with iPhone5 or iPhone5S upon availability may be? Think about your requirement on futuristic development as well.

Comment: @SJuan76, I see what you mean, but in my case I just want to have the collection of phones that can substitute the one (I don't need the collection of phones that it can replace... idk if this generates some sort of problem to JPA). And the extra fields are required in this case as well.

Comment: @karthik-r, so your idea is to create both entities and just mapping Phone4Phone_Map with the `@OneToMany` association?

Comment: Yeah. That's what I feel if I had understood what's your problem :)

Comment: Whatever @Jonathan La'Fey mentioned as answer looks fine. You can tune your code to your requirement if you need it as composite or not. You know the tale structure and the problem better than us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Phone` **has** a list of `Phone4Phone_Map`

You could do the following

The class `Phone` would have many `Phone4Phone_Map` objects

```
class Phone{
    private Integer idPhone;
    private String name;
    private String model;
    private Long price;

    @OneToMany(mappedBY="phone")
    private List<Phone4Phone_Map> phone4Phone_Map;

    //Getters/Setters
}
```

and every instance of the class `Phone4Phone_Map` would reference a phone

If the `foreign_key` in `Phone4Phone_Map` is the `idPhone_out` (the broken phone) the mapping would be:

```
class Phone4Phone_Map{

    private Integer idPhone_in
    private Integer idPhone_out
    private Date valid_since
    private String reason

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idPhone_out")
    private Phone phone;

    //Getters/Setters
}
```

**NOTE** that both classes considered `@Entity`

The field types/names is just for example and you can change them. I avoid other necessary annotations (e.g. `@Id`) to keep the example simple.

With that structure your tables would be

```
Phone:
------
idPhone INT(11) PK
name VARCHAR()
model VARCHAR()
price LONG
```

and

```
Phone4Phone_Map:
----------------
idPhone_in INT(11) PK
idPhone_out INT(11) PK
valid_since TIMESTAMP
reason VARCHAR()
idPhone_out FK references Phone(idPhone)
```

Comment: `idPhone_in` should be a `@OneToOne` with Phone, and `idPhone_out` probably is not needed

Comment: @jonathan-lafey, Your proposal seems to fit my needs, but I have a doubt regarding `idPhone_in` and `idPhone_out` as I thought (in case of creating an entity for `Phone4Phone_Map`) it would be a composite PK. Are you impliying that I should forget about that in this case? I don't see it clearly

Comment: I think OP wants many replacements for 1 phone. Plus, i wanted to keep his table structure as intact as possible.

Comment: `idPhone_out` could or could not be part of the primary_key of your `Phone4Phone_Map`. As **SJuan76** instructed, it;s probably not needed though. It's up to you, i just added it to keep your tables as instact as i could.

**Edit**: if you decide to leave `idPhone_out` out then your `idPhone_in` should be both _primary_key_ and _foreign_key_